# How to proof uniqueness with the usage of function and proving an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

My first problem is connected with showing that there is only one couple of natural numbers which fulfills the condition $$x^y=y^x, \ x<y.$$ Of course these numbers are 2 and 4. It can be done with the help of the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Unfortunately I don't see any connection here.

Second problem associated with the first one is with proving the inequality

$$ \left(\dfrac{33}{32}\right)^{32}<\dfrac{32}{3}.$$
I can't prove in explicitly. Intuitively it is quite clear, but I seek formal proof which does not come to my mind.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer yes, that's why I have written that I consider natural numbers. We assume that $x<y$ so the solution is the only one.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, for some reason I skipped over that when I read initially. My apologies.

Comment: For the first problem, $x^y = y^x$ if and only if $x^{1/x} = y^{1/y}$.  So draw a graph of $f(x) = x^{1/x}$, and I think you will see it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$ we have

$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x<e$$

since the function $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ and approaches $e$.

Therefore

$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{32}\right)^{32}<e<\frac{32}{3} $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint for the first problem**

Note that $x^y = y^x$ can be written as $x^{1/x} = y^{1/y}$. The claim is equivalently asking for $x,y$ with $x < y$ so that $f(x) = f(y)$. You want to show that $(x,y) = (2,4)$ is the only solution.

To do this, try using calculus to show that $f$ does not take on the same value twice (after the exceptions $2,4$). There is a specific function property which is helpful here. It might also help to compute some small values of $f$ (or even better, use software to plot $f$) to get an idea for how the function behaves.

**Hint for the second problem**

Never mind, just do what the other answerer says.

*<s>It looks like they want you to rewrite this in terms of $f$, but honestly, the first solution method that pops into my mind is to use the binomial theorem and bound small terms. In other words, do something like this:
$$ (1 + \frac{1}{32} )^{32} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{32} \cdot 32 + \left( \frac{1}{32} \right)^2 \binom{32}{2} + \dots $$</s>*

Comment: Did you mean that we should show that $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is injection? If so, how to do this formally? I have thought about that previously, but I can't prove it formally.

Comment: The function $f$ is certainly not injective. For example, $f(2) = f(4)$. I meant, as the other answerer explains, that $f$ increases until $x = e$, then decreases.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I understand this in a way that I ought to show that $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $f(y)=y^{\frac{1}{y}}$ have got one joint point. Am I right? Anyway it's hard to show without plotting